Does the GPU version of AutoDock Vina support docking to zinc metalloproteins?
I am trying to follow the zinc metalloprotein docking guide for AutoDock Vina here
https://autodock-vina.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docking_zinc.html
The process in that guide involves creating custom force field maps with zinc parameters to be passed to AutoDock Vina via the —-ffile option.
Vina-GPU, as far as I can tell, doesn’t support the —-ffile option. On the other hand zinc is included in a few places in the Vina-GPU source code, e.g. in atom_constants.h
https://github.com/DeltaGroupNJUPT/Vina-GPU-2.1/blob/main/AutoDock-Vina-GPU-2.1/lib/atom_constants.h
So maybe the necessary parameters for zinc are built in for the GPU version.
I’m hoping that someone can tell me whether or not docking to zinc metalloproteins is officially supported in Vina-GPU.
